# Как обновить определенный тег HTML при получении ответа AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

Создаю свое, первое веб-приложение с помощью Django. 
Использую AJAX для обновления данных в блоках, пример одного в HTML:

```
<span class="ml-3 ajax_block_delete">
    {% include 'workouts/include/inc_input_block_description.html' %}
</span>
```

Включенный шаблон:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ block.id }}" value="{{ block.block_is_delete }}" {% if block.block_is_delete == 1 %} checked {% endif %}>
```

В JS файле код:

```
window.onload = function () { 
    $('.ajax_block_delete').on('change', function (event) {   
        var block_delete = event.target; 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/update/workout/delete/block/" + block_delete.name + "/status/"  + block_delete.value + "/",  
        success: function (data) {  
            $('.ajax_block_delete').html(data.result); 
        },
    });

    event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

По итогу в веб-приложении будет много блоков (у каждого личный `id`, `value`). При изменении `value` из-за строчки `$('.ajax_block_delete').html(data.result)` обновится не только нужный блок, а все на странице, так они имеют общий класс.

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать, чтобы только обновлялся блок в котором произошли изменения.

Comment: у вас сначала удаляется блок, а потом ajax отдает новый список данных, ну а у вас не выходит потому что <span class="ml-3 ajax_block_delete"> таких несколько, я правильно понял?

Comment: к тому же как у вас срабатывает change на span , если это событие применимо только к полям формы?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю сделать так: поставить какой-то класс к полю, например `<input type="checkbox" name="{{ block.id }}" class='bdelete' value="{{ block.block_is_delete }}" {% if block.block_is_delete == 1 %} checked {% endif %}>`, потом немного переписать код JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('input.bdelete').on('change', function (event) {   
        var block_delete = event.target;
    var parentSpan=block_delete.closest("span");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/update/workout/delete/block/" + block_delete.name + "/status/"  + block_delete.value + "/",  
        success: function (data) {  
            $('parentSpan').html(data.result); 
        },
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Проверяйте.

Comment: $(document).ready(), тот же window.onload()

Comment: Спасибо за вариант решения, сделал в соответствии, но не помогло, данные теперь просто не обновляются на странице, в БД сохраняются. 

Мой первый вопрос, еще не совсем правильно описал реализацию, сейчас дополню, что использую подключенный шаблон.